# How to import different classes in one class in JGRASP editor

Tags: java, jgrasp

How to import different class in one class in JGRASP so that I can use the second class's code in the first one? Can someone please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they all share the same package root directory, you don't have to do anything other than use a Java import statement. If they have different root directories or some are jar files, use "Settings" > "PATH / CLASSPATH" > "Workspace" to add jar files and directories on the "CLASSPATHS" tab.